# how can I have read().decode()(python) functionality in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

So here, in the song variable, a title of the song is given and then concatenating that string into the youtube results link.Now read().decode() is converting that html_content into that song ID.So how can I have this functionality in JavaScript?

Python code:

```
        query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query": song})
        html_content = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/results?" + query_string)

        # retrieve all videos that met the song name criteria
        search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
```

Comment: If you are doing it in the browser, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API and if you are using node, I like axios https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use my script below to search for specific keywords and return list of ids.

Live demo: https://replit.com/@kallefrombosnia/js-yt-search#index.js

```
const https = require('https');


/**
 * Define our function
 */
const ytSearchResult = (song) =>{

  // return promised result
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{

    // Send get request to the youtube
    https.get(`https://www.youtube.com/results?q=${encodeURIComponent(song)}&hl=en`, (res) => {

      // Init data string
      let data = '';

      // Append data
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
          data += chunk;
      });

      // Event fired on stream finish
      res.on('end', () => {

        // Our exporting id list 
        let idlist = [];

        // Match all results
        const ids = data.match(/{"url":"\/watch\?v=(.{11})"/g);

        // Parse trough them and get id
        ids.forEach((string, index) =>{

          // Data is not well formated so we need to split returned string
          idlist.push(string.split('=')[1]);
          
          // Check if we have reached end of array
          if((index + 1) === ids.length){
            
            // If yes resolve with id array list
            resolve(idlist);
          }

        });

      });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
        reject(err);
    }); 
  });
}

// Call function
ytSearchResult('best song').then(data => {

  // Log array id
  console.log(data)

}).catch(err => console.log(err.toString()))

/** 
 * Example
 * 
 * [
  'NSRobDsUb54"', 'o_v9MY_FMcw"',
  'k_on7zgBPUA"', 'qclWIFxq2F4"',
  'lyIhRNPCNiw"', 'HPkydJOXXNs"',
  'cW9EdTbkWfc"', '-ObdvMkCKws"',
  'jRS6cGbr3Og"', 'LwOQdoYKQ5k"',
  'HigTewy3OTM"', '5D8KR6_wPU0"',
  'LpfMVFY1TOM"', 'AOMU6qcOFW0"',
  'P51_8HMI150"', 'DQ2Ru2obvQE"',
  'UgfsbL-uHOA"', '4HD_pJpQ4SQ"',
  'X3e2oPpX5ek"', 'cWm8OXGUHZQ"',
  '5mFTXbZzOAE"', 'nntmY825J64"',
  'OlRKpevb-Gs"', 'GKSRyLdjsPA"',
  'o_cikTgwMXY"', 'lbPhbuO4wc4"',
  'Zf94v3vTGQc"', '7zT8omdej4c"'
]
 */
```

Comment: If your request was fulfilled, please mark it as an answer. @BhagyashreeR

Comment: could you please help me , like I wanna have the first video ID only so I change the if condition,  if (index + 1 === 1) {
                // If yes resolve with id array list
                resolve(idlist);
                return;
              }   but its not giving me the desired result...I may be wrong at some place.Please help!!

Comment: You dont need to modify the code above, just select first element from returned array.

// Call function
ytSearchResult('best song').then(data => {

  // Log array id
  console.log(data[0])

}).catch(err => console.log(err.toString()))

It will print NSRobDsUb54

Comment: hey,how can I access data variable out ytSearchResult?